Apps Script slowed by information not used in the script
I am trying to troubleshoot a section of a larger script and when using a Test Workbook the script executes in 15 seconds but in my Final Workbook it takes 4+ minutes and occasionally times out. While my Final Workbook has more data the sheets being referenced in both the Test Workbook & Final Workbook are identical.
Basically, it appears that the size of the workbook impacts the script even if the data being referenced by the script is no different. Am I missing something?
///--------------------------------------------------------------------------///

function Update_Pricing() {
  Browser.msgBox('Message Header'
    ,'message here'
  , Browser.Buttons.OK);  

// Source workbook 
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                                                                              

// Dashboard
  const dash = wb.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
// Finds the Dashboard value to update as Incomplete as the dashboard values occasional move rows
  const dashvalue1 = dash.getRange(1, 2, dash.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().indexOf("Competitor Information Upload") + 1; // **Dashboard lookup value
  const dashrange1 = dash.getRange(dashvalue1, 4);                                                                              // Dashboard date stamp column
  dashrange1.setValue("Incomplete");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Dashboard Updated',' Update',20);

// Retrieve Spreadsheet ID from cell
  const settings = wb.getSheetByName("Ref_Config");                                                                                     // Settings page with ID reference
  const ref_ID = settings.getRange(1, 3, settings.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().indexOf("Khg - Competitor Pricing Workbook") + 1; // **Settings page lookup value
  const srcSpreadsheetId = settings.getRange(ref_ID,4).getValue();                                                                      // Source workbook ID reference
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Spreadsheet ID retrieved, loading data',' Update',60);
  Logger.log(srcSpreadsheetId)

  const srcwb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSpreadsheetId);
  const srcsheet = srcwb.getSheetByName("Summary");                                                           // **Source workbook sheet name
  const srcdata = srcsheet.getRange(2,1,srcsheet.getLastRow()-1,10).getValues()                               // **Get values (row,columnm,optNumRows,OptNumColumnss)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Source values retrieved',' Update',40);
}


Formulas are recalculated when a spreadsheet is opened. Optimizing your spreadsheet to speed this up would be beneficial.
As the question doesn't include details, providing specific guidance is impossible. Please add a [mvcve] to reproduce the problem. For this, you should describe the spreadsheet structure and size as well a summary of formulas used on it. By the way, the function on the question includes too many SpreadsheetApp.flush(); Apparently most of them are not necessary.

I can add a sample but i'm not sure it would be of much assistance. To better understand the issue:

Currently the script is being initiated from the workbook
The workbook is open and no formulas are calculating
The script is also making no changes to the sheet so the formulas will not recalculate at any point. It is only getting values
If run from the Test Workbook no problem, if run from the Final Workbook it times out and the only difference is the size of the data in each workbook which is not used in the script at all
-perhaps an example would be best


What trouble shooting have you done? How about a comparison of each sheet, and looking at the executions log to identify where the extra processing time is being incurred.

Thanks for your reply. The script includes SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() and SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSpreadsheetId); both commands open the corresponding spreadsheet on the server side. Also SpreadsheetApp.flush() might make that the spreadsheet be recalculated. If your spreadsheets makes use of volatile functions and formulas, they are recalculated on every change (every time that SpreadsheetApp.flush() is called).

@MicahNoble formulas will not recalculate at any point I think flush() would force a recalculation, even if you don't see it on the browser. Also use console.time() to time  each part of your script to pinpoint the exact line causing the issue.
